# How do I find the name of a XAML element in C#?

Tags: c#, xaml

I have this code here that will detect if a checkbox has been changed within XAML, therefore also checking the name of that checkbox to see if it matches "whatever". However I can't seem to wrap my head around referring to this attribute, as its one that you declare yourself (`x:Name`).

`checkBox.Name` [throws this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/boI2L.png), which makes it more complicated, as I don't see how I can find the `x:Name` of this element.

```
private void CB_Changed(object sender, CheckedChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            CheckBox checkBox = sender as CheckBox;
            if (checkBox.Name == "whatever")
            {
                  // Do something
            }
        }
```

How would one accomplish this, but obviously in the correct way?

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: "CheckBox does not contain a definition for 'Name'"

Comment: If your editor supports it, try hovering over 'CheckBox' to see in a tooltip what class it is (for example System.Windows.Controls.CheckBox).

Comment: A CheckBox most certainly [has a Name property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.checkbox). Try `var checkBox = sender as System.Windows.Controls.CheckBox;` and see if that works.

Comment: I should've mentioned previously, this is for an android app, so would the same thing apply?

Comment: @mami It says it is apart of Xamarin.Forms, if that helps?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [`AutomationId`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.element.automationid) property.